# Bottom bracket replacement twice during 5000km

Tags: bottom-bracket, internally-geared-hub

I have a bike with CDN gates belt and alfine 11 gear hub. I had to replace bottom bracket twice during 5000km is that normal? It uses BSA 68-120mm thun zumba jis:

https://www.google.com/search?q=BB+THUN+ZUMBA+GBL+440+BSA+JIS+Urban&rlz=1C1WPZC_enCZ931CZ931&oq=BB+THUN+ZUMBA+GBL+440+BSA+JIS+Urban%09%09%09&aqs=chrome..69i57.4023j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

which is really not standard and I am struggling to find some quality alternative to this.

Can you suggest me something good quality - money is no object:)) bun not much more than 100-150 USD:))

Also can this be fixed with something more standard like 68-118 and use some washers or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Phil or Royce bottom brackets have the best reputation. Shimano and Tange after that.

Comment: If you're replacing the bottom bracket anyway, I'd look into converting it to a system with bearing cups where the shaft is not part of the bottom bracket. LIke Shimano Hollowtech II. Much simpler system that also lighter. I don't see any downsides. You'd need a new crank, but it would fit into a budget of 100 bucks.  they usually come with chainrings which are of no use to you. It probably makes sense to move over the belt ring to the new crank. As @nathan_knutson indicated, also have the alignment of the shell thread and face checked.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to try going to a higher quality BB that was 118, yes you could use 1mm spacers along with an appropriate length chainring bolt.

The nicer Shimano units are often the simple option for good quality JIS cartridge units, but it generally doesn't work to put a spacer under the drive side cup shoulder because the adapter cup has a lip that prevents it from sinking into the BB shell any deeper than intended. What you could do is get a 73x118 and put a 3.5mm of BB spacer under the drive side cup shoulder, which will locate the chainline as though it were a 120 and cause a negligible offset to the Q-factor.

As important as chainline (a misnomer) is to belt systems, it might be close enough to just use the 121mm SKF BB if you wanted to go super high end.

Repeat issues with BB wear can sometimes be helped by chasing and facing the shell.

Comment: You would have to use a 3.5 mm spacer with a 73BB in a 68 shell to get that chainline (2.5mm to correct the shell width difference plus the 1mm), and my experience looking at this a couple of weeks ago says there isn't enough thread on a Shimano cartridge bb to do this comfortably.

Comment: Yes, forgot about the 2.5mm spacer part. Despite that, I have done this before on heavily ridden bikes and felt like there was enough thread engagement. There might be different amounts of threaded length there on different Shimano BBs. I can certainly imagine takign 3.5mm away leaving not enough.